# The json data i am putting into a pug template is putting '<' at the beginning of a string and '>' at the end. why? how do i get rid of it?

Tags: node.js, json, express, pug

So i have a json file with a json array

```
    {
    "LunchItems": [
    {
        "name":" The Strange Brew",
        "price":"~6~",
        "description":" A Classic Irish Style Beer Cheese Soup Garnished with Red Pepper and Toasted Baguette"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Killer Tomato",
        "price":"~6~",
        "description":" A Roma Tomato and Roasted Red Pepper Bisque Garnished with Spiced Creme Fraiche"
    },
    {
        "name":" House Salad",
        "price":" ~7~",
        "description":" Spring Mix, Carrot, Red Onion, Roma Tomato, Mushroom and Red Peppers"
    },
    {
        "name":" Mediterranean Salad",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" Spring Mix, Red Onion, Kalamata Olives, Roma Tomato, Capers and Feta Cheese"
    },
    {
        "name":" Side Salad & Cup Of Soup",
        "price":"~6~",
        "description":" "
    },
    {
        "name":" The Ollie",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" A Quarter Pound Version of Our Signature Stout Burger Served on a Pretzel Roll with Spring Mix, Roma Tomato, Red Onion & Colby Jack Cheese - With Choice Of Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Neuben",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" Grilled Corned Beef Topped with Sauerkraut, Grilled Onions, Swiss Cheese and Stout Mustard Served on a Toasted Pretzel Roll - With Your Choice Of One Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Three Little Birds",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" House Made Chicken Salad Served On 3 Pretzel Rolls with Swiss Cheese and Roma Tomato - With Choice Of Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Fresh Prince",
        "price":" ~8~",
        "description":" Chopped Filet, Onion, Red Pepper & Swiss Served On a Toasted Sausage Roll with Au Jus & Garlic Aioli - With Choice Of Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Nine Iron",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" Corned Beef, Smoked Turkey, Benton's© Bacon, Swiss, Spring Mix, Red Onion, Tomato, & Garlic Aioli - With Choice Of Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Fish 'n' Chips",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" Two Beer Battered Cod Filets Served with House Made Tartare Sauce and Malt Vinegar Aioli - With Choice Of Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Big Cheese",
        "price":"~6~",
        "description":" A Classic Colby Jack & Sourdough Grilled Cheese Sandwich - With Choice Of Side"
    },
    {
        "name":" The Chicken Gyro",
        "price":"~9~",
        "description":" Grilled chicken breast with spring mix, roma tomato, red onion and feta cheese wrapped in toasted pita bread and served with house made tzatziki sauce - with choice of one side."
    },
    {
        "name":" Deluxe Quesadilla",
        "price":"~8~",
        "description":" Colby Jack, Roasted Corn, Red Peppers, Black Beans & Red Onion Served with House Salsa & Spiced Creme Fraiche"
    },
    {
        "name":" Cheese Quesadilla",
        "price":"~5~",
        "description":" Cheese quesadilla served with house salsa & spiced creme fraiche"
    }
]
}
```

I am using express to render pug files

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const lunches = require('./public/json/lunch.json');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
  });

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index',{
      lunches: lunches.LunchItems
    });
  });
```

```
    doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/Index.css')
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    style. 
        body { 
            background-image: url("/images/wood.jpg"); 
            background-size: auto;
        }
  body
    div.menuContainer
        each item in lunches
            div.menuItem 
                #{item.name} <br/>
                #{item.price} <br/>
                #{item.description}
```

the output is:
 < The Strange Brew>

<~6~>

< A Classic Irish Style Beer Cheese Soup Garnished with Red Pepper and Toasted Baguette>

< The Killer Tomato>

<~6~>

< A Roma Tomato and Roasted Red Pepper Bisque Garnished with Spiced Creme Fraiche>...

So why are the '<>' there and how do i get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a new line with `#{variable}`, Pug thinks you're wanting to use block-level tag interpolation:

> **Tag Interpolation**
>
> Pug:
>
> ```
> - let myTag = 'h1';
> #{myTag} Heading
> ```
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <h1>Heading</h1>
> ```

If you want to just render text on multiple new lines, you can use the [piped (`|`) text syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#piped-text), the [block text syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) (with a `.` after the tag), or [inline tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation) for the line breaks:

**Piped Text Example**

```
div.menuItem 
  | #{item.name}
  br
  | #{item.price}
  br
  | #{item.description}
```

**Block Text Example**

```
div.menuItem. // note the trailing dot
  #{item.name}<br/>
  #{item.price}<br/>
  #{item.description}
```

**Inline Tag Interpolation Example**

```
div.menuItem #{item.name} #[br] #{item.price} #[br] #{item.description}
```

These should all yield the same desired result.

Alternatively, a more semantic solution could be to use a [description list (`dl`) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) to mark up this information.

**Alternative Example**

```
article.menuItem
  h1 #{item.name}
  dl
    dt Price
    dd #{item.price}
    dt Description
    dd #{item.description}
```

Comment: Yo thank you. I had seen something about piped text but was not sure where i had found that. Also thanks for the pointer on the dl element.

Comment: @zaccantrell The official docs have answers to most of the questions that come up